# How to maintain different aws profiles in terraform provider configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have two AWS env each has one profile Dev for QA env and prod for prod env.

here I would like to maintain single provider configuration block in terraform with multiple profiles as per the env, lets say an if kind of condition to select the profile based on env key.

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  profile = "dev". (this profile should be taken as per the env type)
  default_tags {
    terraform = true
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I personally think it is a very bad idea to let terraform know anything about profiles or specific credentials or assuming roles. Instead when calling terraform you need to make sure to set the right credentials, the right profile, assume the right role, etc. That is nothing that terraform should need to worry about.

Comment: Thank you Luk for your inputs on my query. I am passing the profile information to code either through variables or locals only, actual profile information including the Access and secret keys are maintained inside the pipeline.

Comment: Yes I know but still I would not set the profile in the provider but instead run the code, e.g. with `AWS_PROFILE=dev terraform plan`.

Comment: Or alternatively define two `provider` blocks and use the `alias` option when required.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the provider without aws Profile
that way TF will apply it on the relevant profile.

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  //profile = "dev". (this profile should be taken as per the env type)
  default_tags {
    terraform = true
  }
}
```

than change your active profile and default aws profile

```
AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=dev
AWS_PROFILE=dev
```

and run the TF

```
terrafotm apply
```